# How to get the row index of a csv file in java

Tags: java, arrays, csv

My program is to validate if the input code number is empty or not. The condition is if there is a code number entered(thru csv file) proceed and if code number is empty an error message show. "The code number is empty in line :__".
My problem is how can I suppose to print the index of a line on which the code number was empty.

Here's my sample data(csv):

```
CRITERIA  CODE  NAME  AGE ADDRESS
ADD       0001  JOHN  21  USA
ADD             MICH  16  EUR
ADD             ALI   11  PHL
```

Error Message should be :

```
"The code number is empty in line 2."
"The code number is empty in line 3."
```

Here's my current program :

```
private static String[] sNextLine2; 
public static Map<String,Employee> getChanges
( String sFileName, Map<String, Employee> mEmployeeList )
throws IOException {
                                    //Read_File
    setReader2(new CSVReader(new FileReader(sFileName)));
    while ((sNextLine2 = reader2.readNext()) != null) { 
    switch(sNextLine2[0]) {
        case "ADD":         
            if(sNextLine2[1].isEmpty()) {
                System.out.println("The code number is empty in line" + lineNumber); //how to get that line number

            } else if (mEmployeeList.containsKey(sNextLine2[1]))
            {
                System.out.println("Data already exist");
            }
            else
            {
                mEmployeeList.put(sNextLine2[1],new Employee(sNextLine2[1],
                        sNextLine2[2], sNextLine2[3], sNextLine2[4], sNextLine2[5],
                        sNextLine2[6], sNextLine2[7], sNextLine2[8]));
            }

            break;
    }
```

I hope someone will help me on this. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can add a counter, which is incremented every `.readNext()` and let it print if there is an error

```
 int counter=0;
 while ((sNextLine2 = reader2.readNext()) != null) { 
    counter++;
    switch(sNextLine2[0]) {
        case "ADD":         
            if(sNextLine2[1].isEmpty()) {
                System.out.println("The code number is empty in line" + counter); //how to get that line number

            } else if (mEmployeeList.containsKey(sNextLine2[1]))
            {
                System.out.println("Data already exist");
            }
            else
            {
                mEmployeeList.put(sNextLine2[1],new Employee(sNextLine2[1],
                        sNextLine2[2], sNextLine2[3], sNextLine2[4], sNextLine2[5],
                        sNextLine2[6], sNextLine2[7], sNextLine2[8]));
            }

            break;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you so much you're amazing! you got it in just a minute.